# Bash: oil: command not found, error

Tags: git, fuelphp

$  oil generate model users username:varchar[50] password:string group:int email:string last_login:int login_hash:string profile_fields:text

**bash: oil: command not found**

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to run `php oil generate ...` as documented here: http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/oil/generate.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use oil as a command, you need to install it:

```
$ curl get.fuelphp.com/oil | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Like WanWizard told, just make sure you have *oil* command in your computer at a right path.
If so, possibly the *oil* command does not have proper permissions to execute if you're on Uni* environment, so *chmod* may help to give executable permission or try explicitly specifying *php* command beforehand like this.

```
$ /usr/bin/php oil generate model users username:varchar[50] password:string group:int email:string last_login:int login_hash:string profile_fields:text
```